# Problema con funciones y bucles en C

Tags: c, funciones, bucle-for, bucles

El problema consta de pedir al usuario 10 números
para después denominar cuales son pares

para después mostrarlos en pantalla

y por ultimo si se ingresan la totalidad de 10 números impares decir por pantalla que no hay ningún numero par

bueno todo esto usando funciones

ahora bien el problema en si ya lo resolví pero cuando ingreso los 10 números impares

El programa igualmente me devuelve el mensaje con los números pares  vacío obviamente el tema es que no se como hacer para que esto no suceda

intente hacer 2 funciones por separado pero ahora el programa se cuelga

Adjunto el código a continuación desde ya muchas gracias.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int numerosPares(int numeros){
    int par=0,impar=0;
    int pares[10];
    int num[10];
    int impares[10];

            for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
            if (num[i]%2==0){
        pares[par++]=num[i];
        }
        else{
        impares[impar++]=num[i];
        }
    }    
        printf("Los numeros pares son: ");
        
        for (int i = 0; i <par; i++){
        printf(" %i",pares[i]);
        }
                printf("\n");
}
int numerosImpares(int numeros){
    int par=0,impar=0;
    int pares[10];
    int num[10];
    int impares[10];

            for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
            if (num[i]%2==0){
        pares[par++]=num[i];
        }
        else{
        impares[impar++]=num[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<impar; i++){
        }
            }   
        if (impar==10){
            printf("La tabla no tiene numeros pares\n");
            system("pause");
            exit(-1);
}
}
int main(){
     int numeros[10];
     int i;

    printf("Ingrese 10 numeros introducidos uno por uno: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
        printf("numero :");scanf("%i",&numeros[i]);
        }

    numerosImpares(numeros[i]);
    numerosPares(numeros[i]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creo que no hace falta realizar dos funciones, con una sola bastaria ya que al preguntar si tu numero es par sabes que si no lo es, va a terminar siendo impar.

Comment: si mi problema es que como hago que no se impriman los dos mensajes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con una sola función es suficiente (y mas eficiente). Por ejemplo, definis la funcion `void analizarNumeros(int n)` y haces exactamente lo mismo que esta en tu codigo, solo que ahora para resolver tu problema lo haces con un if: si el tamanio de`impares[]=10` entonces imprimis `"La tabla no tiene numeros pares\n"`. Luego con el else (o sea que hay al menos un numero par en `pares[])`) imprimis `"Los numeros pares son: "`. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: gracias si eso soluciono el problema supongo que me abrume un poco pero nada grave buen resto de jornada

Comment: estoy más seguro que si sirve.